# How to efficiently modify datetime object in series of a pandas framework

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas data frame, which contains columns of "Date", "Hour", "Minute" and "Second". It has 8000+ rows.

"Date" column is already a datetime type series when created. 
The data types in the data frame is

[image: data]

The goal is to modify the "Date" column data to be a datetime object which contains the Date and corresponding "Hour", "Minute" and "Second" in that row.

So far, I could only do this by the using the replace method in iterations:

```
for i in range(0,len(dfExcel['Date'])):
    dfExcel['Date'][i]=dfExcel['Date'][i].replace(hour=dfExcel['Hour'][i])
```

It takes extremely long time to complete(several mins). Any other ways to complete the task faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
hour, minute, second = pd.to_timedelta(['1H', '1M', '1S'])

df['Date'] += df['Hour'] * hour + df['Min'] * minute + df['Seconds'] * second
```